# Spring Social integration

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-social

I need to integrate ***Spring Social Facebook,Twitter and Google  for SignUp and Login***.

I added all `dependency` related to Spring social i.e. `spring-social-config, spring-social-core, spring-social-web,spring-social-security` also created bin:

```
@Bean
    public ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator() {
        ConnectionFactoryRegistry registry = new ConnectionFactoryRegistry();
        registry.addConnectionFactory(new FacebookConnectionFactory(
            env.getProperty("facebook.clientId"),
            env.getProperty("facebook.clientSecret")));
        return registry;
    }
```

`facebook.clientId` and `facebook.clientSecret` is in Properties file.

I followed [Spring social facebook documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-social-facebook/docs/1.1.x/reference/htmlsingle/#configuring-facebook-connectivity) but i won't understand how to start with this.

Please just let me know how to start with this.

Comment: It should be noted that Java's "Spring Social" has older version of  Facebook API integrated in it. It makes calls to Facebook API's older version which might get deprecated anytime by Facebook, even Facebook warns of those calls to "deprecated" version or "older" versions once you use Spring-social's Facebook integration.

Comment: Thanks @sumitbadaya for response. I asked this question more than year backs.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to solve your issue is to create a property file. The documentation you're looking for is: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html.

If you uses Spring boot, all you have to do is putting those values in /application.properties:

```
facebook.clientId=clientId
facebook.clientSecret=secret
```

If you don't use boot, or if you want to specify another property file:

```
@PropertySource("classpath:/app.properties")
```